# FedEx Warning: The returned rate types are in the requested preferred currency; preferred rates not returned. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fedex

When I want to get rates from FedEx, I am getting this warning.

```
"Severity" => "WARNING"
"Source" => "crs"
"Code" => "396"
"Message" => "The returned rate types are in the requested preferred currency; preferred rates not returned."
"LocalizedMessage" => "The returned rate types are in the requested preferred currency; preferred rates not returned."
```

I used https://github.com/JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper to get rates from FedEx.

Controller:

```
$rateRequest->RequestedShipment->ShippingChargesPayment->PaymentType = PaymentType::_SENDER;
$rateRequest->RequestedShipment->PreferredCurrency = 'USD';
$rateRequest->RequestedShipment->RateRequestTypes = [RateRequestType::_PREFERRED, RateRequestType::_LIST];
```

Comment: Did you try to ask here https://github.com/JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/issues?

Comment: Not yet. I will ask now. I don't think that I will receive reply.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also struck in the same problem.

Comment: Have you asked this in the issues? can you send me a link to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

just a workaround

you can change the preferred_currency to the country the package is being shipped.

like if the package is being deliverd to Australia then pass the currency AUD in the preferred_currency and USD as the currency of the amount of the package or commodities or insured value. then it does include the preferred rates and also the conversion rate and then you can convert back to USD after the response

by doing this I get this in the response. as you can see the exchange rate is available and you can convert back to USD

```
"ShipmentRateDetail": {
    "RateType": "PREFERRED_ACCOUNT_SHIPMENT",
    "RateScale": "US001OFJ_03_YOUR_PACKAGING",
    "RateZone": "US001O",
    "RatedWeightMethod": "ACTUAL",
    "CurrencyExchangeRate": {
        "FromCurrency": "USD",
        "IntoCurrency": "AUD",
        "Rate": "1.53"
    },
    "DimDivisor": 166,
    "DimDivisorType": "PRODUCT",
    "FuelSurchargePercent": "21.0",
    "TotalBillingWeight": {
        "Units": "LB",
        "Value": "15.0"
    },
    "TotalBaseCharge": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "713.23"
    },
    "TotalFreightDiscounts": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "611.96"
    },
    "TotalNetFreight": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "101.27"
    },
    "TotalSurcharges": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "25.26"
    },
    "TotalNetFedExCharge": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "126.53"
    },
    "TotalTaxes": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "0.0"
    },
    "TotalNetCharge": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "126.53"
    },
    "TotalRebates": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "0.0"
    },
    "TotalDutiesAndTaxes": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "0.0"
    },
    "TotalAncillaryFeesAndTaxes": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "0.0"
    },
    "TotalDutiesTaxesAndFees": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "0.0"
    },
    "TotalNetChargeWithDutiesAndTaxes": {
        "Currency": "AUD",
        "Amount": "126.53"
    },
    "FreightDiscounts": {
        "RateDiscountType": "VOLUME",
        "Description": "Volume",
        "Amount": {
            "Currency": "AUD",
            "Amount": "611.96"
        },
        "Percent": "85.8"
    },
    "Surcharges": [
        {
            "SurchargeType": "INSURED_VALUE",
            "Description": "Insured value",
            "Amount": {
                "Currency": "AUD",
                "Amount": "3.99"
            }
        },
        {
            "SurchargeType": "OTHER",
            "Description": "Demand Surcharge",
            "Amount": {
                "Currency": "AUD",
                "Amount": "0.0"
            }
        },
        {
            "SurchargeType": "FUEL",
            "Description": "Fuel",
            "Amount": {
                "Currency": "AUD",
                "Amount": "21.27"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}